# email google spreadsheet as html

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a google script that emails out a spreadsheet as html.  I am trying to convert the spreadsheet to html using the export url, but currently google docs only lets you export it out as a zip.  Is there a way to get the html representation of a spreadsheet worksheet?

```
function getDocAsHtml(docId){ 
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + docId + "/exportFormat?format=html";
  var fetch=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+docId).get
  return fetch;
```

}

Comment: your solution is there : written by a well known contributor on this site https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-range/dolojkflgagmliddfokeajaohhbojgdm

Answer (score 1):

Publish the sheet that you want to get the HTML out of:

- File Menu, PUBLISH TO WEB

[image: Publish to Web]

Make sure that:  "Automatically Republish When Changes Are Made" is checked.

Get the URL of the published page.  Use that URL in a `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` request.

Use `UrlFetchApp` to get the content of that published sheet.

```
function fncSheetToHTML() { 
  var theSheetContents = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/YourID_Here/pubhtml?gid=123abc&single=true");
  Logger.log("theSheetContents: " + theSheetContents);
}
```

The returned contents is a string.  If you view the LOGS of what is returned from the above code, you'll see HTML tags in the content.

The published sheet is visible to anyone who uses that URL.  So, if you don't want people to see the contents, this method might not be what you want.  If you don't share that published URL, I don't know how likely it is that anyone will ever find it.